# '_Screen' object has no attribute 'onTimer'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

For some reason my code that was working perfectly fine suddenly stopped working when I opened up my project today, here is my snippet of code that is not working.

```
import turtle
running = True
wn = turtle.Screen()
TimeTurtle = turtle.Turtle()

def setTime():
    global Time
    global running
    if running:
        Time = Time + 1
        TimeTurtle.clear()
    TimeTurtle.write("Time: " + str(Time), align="center", font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))
    wn.onTimer(setTime, 1000)
```

I get the error: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'onTimer'
Any help?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. I ran your snippet and only got `NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined`.

Comment: [module object has no attribute 'Screen'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6006871/669576)

Comment: @Kevin Fixed, forgot to import turtle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wn.onTimer(setTime, 1000)
```

I don't see an `onTimer` method listed anywhere in the [turtle documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html). Perhaps you want [`ontimer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer), with a lowercase T?

```
wn.ontimer(setTime, 1000)
```